# hide row count in qtablewidget and color columns

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

In my project I've faced the problem of hiding row count in `QTableWidget`, I need to display the table but without row numbers and borders, here is standard `QTableWidget`.

[image: standart table]

how to hide row count and borders of cells and color the colums, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the property of QTableWidget. Provided you are using qt-creator, just right click on your table widget in your form(name.ui) and click edit items and then untick translatable property for rows and column. You can change the color of column by changing its stylesheet.

Comment: How does the "translatable property" affect what part of the table should be shown?